# How to implement KAZE and A-KAZE using Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, feature-descriptor

I am trying to implement `KAZE` and `A-KAZE` using **Python** and **OpenCV** for **Feature Detection and Description** on an aerial image.

What is the code?

Also, what descriptor should go along with it for **Feature Matching**?

Answer (score 20):

`KAZE`, as well as some previous state-of-the-art methods such as `SIFT` and `SURF`, are **Local Feature Descriptors**, and in some ways, it shows better performance in both **detection** and **description** compared to `SIFT` descriptor. `A-KAZE`, on the other hand, is a **Local Binary Descriptor** and presents excellent results in terms of speed and performance compared to state-of-the-art methods such as **Local Feature Descriptors**: `SIFT`, `SURF`, and `KAZE`, and compared to **Local Binary Descriptors**: `ORB`, and `BRISK`.

Responding to your question, both of them can go along with it for **Feature Matching**, although, `A-KAZE` descriptor do not fit appropriately in smaller patches (e.g., smallest images — 32x32 patch), that is, in order to avoid the return of keypoints without descriptors, `A-KAZE` normally remove the keypoints.

Therefore, the choice between `KAZE` and `A-KAZE` depends on the context of your application. But, a priori `A-KAZE` has a better performance than `KAZE`.

In this example, I will show you **Feature Detection and Matching** with `A-KAZE` through the `FLANN` algorithm using **Python** and **OpenCV**.

First, load the input image and the image that will be used for training.

In this example, we are using those images:

`image1`:

[image]

`image2`:

[image]

```
# Imports
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Open and convert the input and training-set image from BGR to GRAYSCALE
image1 = cv.imread(filename = 'image1.jpg',
                   flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image2 = cv.imread(filename = 'image2.jpg',
                   flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Note that when importing the images, we use the `flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter, because in **OpenCV** the default color mode setting is **BGR**. Therefore, to work with **Descriptors**, we need to convert the color mode pattern from **BGR** to **grayscale**.

Now we will use the `A-KAZE` algorithm:

```
# Initiate A-KAZE descriptor
AKAZE = cv.AKAZE_create()

# Find the keypoints and compute the descriptors for input and training-set image
keypoints1, descriptors1 = AKAZE.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = AKAZE.detectAndCompute(image2, None)
```

The **features** detected by the `A-KAZE` algorithm can be combined to find objects or patterns that are similar between different images.

Now we will use the `FLANN` algorithm:

```
# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1

index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE,
                    trees = 5)

search_params = dict(checks = 50)

# Convert to float32
descriptors1 = np.float32(descriptors1)
descriptors2 = np.float32(descriptors2)

# Create FLANN object
FLANN = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(indexParams = index_params,
                             searchParams = search_params)

# Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN Matcher
matches = FLANN.knnMatch(queryDescriptors = descriptors1,
                         trainDescriptors = descriptors2,
                         k = 2)

# Lowe's ratio test
ratio_thresh = 0.7

# "Good" matches
good_matches = []

# Filter matches
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < ratio_thresh * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

# Draw only "good" matches
output = cv.drawMatches(img1 = image1,
                        keypoints1 = keypoints1,
                        img2 = image2,
                        keypoints2 = keypoints2,
                        matches1to2 = good_matches,
                        outImg = None,
                        flags = cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

And the output will be:

[image]

To perform the same example with the `KAZE` descriptor, just initialize this descriptor, changing:

```
AKAZE = cv.AKAZE_create()
```

To:

```
KAZE = cv.KAZE_create()
```

To learn more about **Detection**, **Description**, and **Feature Matching** techniques, **Local Feature Descriptors**, **Local Binary Descriptors**, and algorithms for **Feature Matching**, I recommend the following repositories on **GitHub**:

- https://github.com/whoisraibolt/Feature-Detection-and-Description
- https://github.com/whoisraibolt/Feature-Detection-and-Matching

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe is the best solution, please, mark this answer as accepted! Thank you!

Comment: This is a pretty comprehensive answer. The question asked is too open-ended for an SO question, but you have done a good job answering it.